# Select into Map using Database.query()

Tags: soql, map, dynamic-soql

So we all know it is possible to directly select into a Map, like this:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
```

Is it possible to do the same thing, using Database.query()?

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account'));
```

Sadly the latter doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It could be that this is one scenario where the "magic casting" of `Database.query` doesn't work quite right.

How about:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>((List<Account>)Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account'));
```

Any luck?

Comment: Since you were first by 6 seconds - I'll accept yours. :)

Answer (score 11):

If you cast it to a List of the expected sObject type first it will work.

E.g.

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = 
    new Map<Id, Account>((List<Account>)Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account'));
```

Comment: Ha! Beat you by 6 seconds. Just long enough to crack open a beer with my lovely deployment fish bottle opener :)

Comment:  I saw that quick edit in the 5 minute window. :)

Comment: Hah yes, just a formatting gaffe.

Comment: I could swear that I tried casting it but - but obviously I didn't. It's working now.

Answer (score 10):

Adding a bit of info here on top of other answers.

This works:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Account]);
```

Because the return type from the SOQL is that of `Account`.

This does not work:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account'));
```

Because the return type of `Database.query` is always `SObject[]`. So unless you ***cast*** the return type to the exact object type, it won't work.

---

Working versions.

Use `SObject` in your declaration

```
Map<Id, SObject> accounts = new Map<Id, SObject>(Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account'));
```

OR

As in other answers, cast it to list/array of account:

```
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>((Account[])Database.query('SELECT Id, Name FROM Account'));
```